# reference another word template

Tags: vba, templates, reference, ms-word

I have a document template (.dot) which references another template (another .dot file). How does it get used? Does it get compiled beforehand and then the compiled version is stored somewhere in the temp folder? Or maybe the referenced template is compiled once before the VBA code in the referenced template is being used for the first time?
I am asking because I have a strange problem: I've corrected a bug in my referenced template, but the other template that references it behaves as if it uses the old (unmodified) template!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140287%28v=office.10%29.aspx#odc_wdtemp_mark6), the first vba executed is the document one, then the vba from the attached template and the vba from the attached attached template.